# Jbehave get Story name inside @BeforeStory

Tags: jbehave

I would like to get the Story name in a method annotated with `@BeforeStory`.

I need this for debugging purposes, cause i'm running a bunch of stories with `runStoriesAsPaths` and with multiple threads, and I'm trying to log which thread is running which story.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you need to create a new StoryReporter (extend that class). In that class you can add actions to be performed before/after story/scenario/step, and you have the story name.
example:

```
public class NewStoryReporter implements StoryReporter {

private StoryReporter delegate;

public NewStoryReporter(StoryReporter delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
public void beforeStory(Story story, boolean givenStory) {
    delegate.beforeStory(story, givenStory);
}

@Override
public void beforeScenario(String scenarioTitle) {
    delegate.beforeScenario(scenarioTitle);
}

@Override
public void beforeStep(String step) {
    if(step.equals("When after each step")){
        return;
    }
    delegate.beforeStep(step);
}
```

then you need to extend StoryReporterBuilder, this creates your NewStoryReporter.
example:

```
public class NewStoryReporterBuilder extends StoryReporterBuilder {

@Override
public StoryReporter build(String storyPath) {
    StoryReporter delegate = super.build(storyPath);
    return new NewStoryReporter(delegate);
}

}
```

then in your configuration, create an instance of the NewStoryReporterBuilder, and use it in

```
Configuration configuration = new YourConfiguration().useStoryReporterBuilder(newStoryReporterBuilder....)
```

Comment: It might have been because I'm running my tests with threads. I ended up having to wrap ConcurrentStoryReporter and creating a custom build method in the `NewStoryReportBuilder` instead of calling super.build()

Answer (score 0):

Now in Jbehave it's configured in different way.

So, to achieve that goal you need to:

1. Create new class which extends org.jbehave.core.reporters.ConsoleOutput. Here you can modify various of methods. In your case - you need to override method:

   ```
   public void beforeScenario(String title)
   ```

   Check example attached in the end of this post to see how it can be done.
2. Create new instance of abstract class org.jbehave.core.reporters.Filter:

   ```
   public static final Format YOUR_CUSTOM_CONSOLE = new Format("YOUR_CUSTOM_CONSOLE")
   {
       @Override
       public StoryReporter createStoryReporter(FilePrintStreamFactory factory,
               StoryReporterBuilder storyReporterBuilder) {
           return new TeamCityConsoleOutput(storyReporterBuilder.keywords()).doReportFailureTrace(
                   storyReporterBuilder.reportFailureTrace()).doCompressFailureTrace(
                   storyReporterBuilder.compressFailureTrace());
       }
   };
   ```
3. Then you need to add this format to your story builder which you are using in your configuration, that mean:

   ```
   new MostUsefulConfiguration()
               .useStoryReporterBuilder(
                       new StoryReporterBuilder()
                               ....//here are another modifications of sorey report builder
                               .withFormats(YOUR_CUSTOM_CONSOLE , .../* another formats */ HTML, Format.XML, Format.TXT))
               ....//here are another modifications of configuration
               .useStepMonitor(new CrossReference().getStepMonitor());
   ```

Here is example of such modification, which can be used to integration with TeamCity:
https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/d15774bf763875662869cdc89ce924b1086af6f8/jbehave-core/src/main/java/org/jbehave/core/reporters/TeamCityConsoleOutput.java